# Sidebar position - moving into other elements when window size reduced

Tags: css, css-position

Building in HTML and CSS, first and foremost.

I am trying to create a quick-links sidebar that is not the main nav bar and not fixed directly to a side but more indented and closer to the central content, if that makes sense. I want it to remain in a fixed position relative to the central content section and fixed top navbar however I have only been able to anchor it to the top and right(as you'll see in my code below). This creates the issue of when I reduce the window size this quick-links bar moves over the central content.

What I am looking to achieve is that the quick-link sidebar would start to move off of the page when it meets the main content section rather than overlap and move into the content section. Essentially it would move as close to the main content section as possible and then start to be removed from the page.

Main content DIV = 825px
Sidebar content DIV = 170px

So something along the lines of once they meet the window would be 995px and then the sidebar would be pushed from the screen.

Sorry to ask but having searched for quite a while I have not been able to find an answer and I am hoping someone here may be of use.

Please note I have removed all of the content for the main section on the basis that no one is going to want to read all of that!

Here is the code:

CSS:

```
    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*-------------Navigation Bar-------------*/

.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    word-spacing: 2.5em;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
    padding: 10;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    z-index: 10;
    }

.navbar ul {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px;
}

.navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    padding: 0px 60px;
    color: black;
}
.navbar li a:hover{
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;

}

.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/*---------------Side Bar-----------------*/

.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 230px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 300px;
    right: 230px;
    border: 4px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 2px;
    background-color: rgb(222, 238, 129);
    clear: right;
}
.sidebar:hover {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.sidebar h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
}
.sidebar p {
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width: 170px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 15px;  
    font-weight: bold;

}
.sidebar p:hover:hover {
    
    background-color: rgb(222, 238, 129);
}

.sidebar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
}
/*----------------Banner------------------*/

#banner {
    background-image: url("../images/banner.png");
    background-size: 825px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 350px;
    width: 825px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

#banner .content {
    width: 300px;
    color: rgb(222, 238, 129);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 40px;
    right: 220px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    border: solid rgb(222, 238, 129) 3px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);     
}


/*----------------Main -------------------*/  


.main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: justify;
    max-width: 825px;
    min-width: 200px;
    font-family: lato, sans-serif;
    color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 1);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    
}

.main .quote {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    position: static;
    
}

.main hr {
    width: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.main p{
    max-width: 825;
    min-width: 200;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.main h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\Coding\Projects\VisualStudioCode\hello_html\practice\CSS\real.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>INsert Content</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- Navigation Bar-->

        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">INsert Content</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <!-- Side Bar-->
        <div class="sidebar" id="grad">
            <h2><u>Quick Links</u></h2>
            <p><a href="">Latest Blog Post</a></p>
            <p><a href="">Learning Resources</a></p>
            <p><a href="">Useful Tips</a></p>
            
            

        </div>


    <!-- Banner-->
        <div id="banner">
            <div class="content">
                insert content
            </div>

        </div>

    <!---- Main content ----->

        <div class="main">
            <div class="quote">
                insert content
            </div>
            <hr>
            <p>insert content</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance and I hope this was not a shocker of a question!

Comment: Hi @Jozzie, Welcome to SO. What specifically are you trying to achieve. May be I can help :-) You have your QuickLinks sidebar. As I can see in the code in the output it is position:fixed; https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/full/xxRVwaJ Where is the issue my friend:-) ?

Comment: Hi Imran, The issue is that I would like for the quick-link sidebar to be moved off of the screen when the window size is reduced rather than over running into the main content section and covering the content and essentially looking very bad. Does that make some sense? I'll update the main question also.

Comment: Towards left or right? I mean do you want to completely remove this on smaller screens or move it towards left or right?

Comment: You would need to use media query for the different screens. If you see the code even now on the full screen and you scroll down, the input field kind of overlaps with your sidebar. You have to plan Design in a way that works for mobile, tablet and other screens. Then use Media Queries as per your Designs. For Example, on small screens there should be a toggle Hamburger for Header. Many things need to be changed in the code dear.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have tio wait until I am further along in my coding journey to implement this then.

Comment: Yup my friend. Keep learning step by step. Learning is a gradual process. I wish you all the best, and if you want any free online resources as per your experience, I may suggest few :-)